# How do I read this chart about a FIFA World Cup game from Google?

Tags: football, world-cup, match-report

Throughout the World Cup the Google Doodle has been FIFA themed, and clicking it takes you to a search for the latest game. Today it's [United States vs Portugal](https://www.google.com/search?q=United+States+vs+Portugal&oi=ddle).

The search brings up a chart which appears to be a summary of the game. It looks like it should be obvious what everything means but I can't make heads or tails of it.

Is this a standard football (soccer) game chart?

If so, how is it meant to be read?

Is there a key available?

Full chart reproduced below in case Google results change.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The timeline shows the major events in the match.

I will try to explain by using few events as shown in your example timeline.
The number in bracket always indicates the respective player’s jersey number.

- 5'  Nani (#17) 0 – 1 Portugal: a goal was scored by Nani for Portugal.
- 16' Portugal made a subtitution, in which Hélder Postiga (#23) was replaced by Éder (#11).
- 46' Portugal made a subtitution, in which André Almeida (#19) was replaced by William (#6).
- 64' Jermaine Jones (#13) United States 1 – 1: a goal was scored by Jermaine Jones for USA.
- 75' Jermaine Jones (#13) gets a yellow card (see the color of the card shown)
- 90+1' First minute of stoppage time, USA makes a substitution.
- 90+5' Fifth minute of stoppage time --> a second goal was scored by Silvestre Varela (#18) for Portugal.

There is additional time allotted after the standard 90 minutes are over. 
Please refer to [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4998/does-stoppage-time-actually-equal-all-non-playing-time-during-a-half).

The rest of the timeline can be read using the above examples.

I believe this is a pretty standard timeline chart for a football match.

Comment: That helps but there are still questions. In the timeline, what does "90 + 1'" mean? What is the boxed event with Jermaine Jones at 75'? And is this a standard way to chart a soccer game or is it something Google just made up?

Comment: @Robert the boxed events are just because of the videos.