# How exactly is the stoppage time determined?

Tags: rules, football

What is the formula (I'm not sure it exists at all, maybe it's just a random number) to determine the amount of extra (added) time in futbol (soccer) that get's added after the obligatory 90 minutes.

- I think that it should be the sum of every action that wastes time. Like injuries, corners, etc.
- I almost see, from 1 minute, up to 5 minutes, never more than that.

---

Related:
[Does stoppage time actually equal all non-playing time during a half?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4998/does-stoppage-time-actually-equal-all-non-playing-time-during-a-half)

Comment: http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/was-the-u-s-robbed-against-portugal-it-depends-on-what-time-means/ may prove helpful in understanding